# Extract html text by vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning VBA to extract text from website. i want to extract 26/05/2018 14:51 and the innertext did not work properly.

The code from the website:

```
<label class="wtext">
    Refreshed at:
    <span id="lastRefreshTime">26/05/2018 14:51</span>
    &nbsp;
</label>
```

the below is my code but it does not work out.

```
Set MDate= html.getElementsByClassName("wtext")(1).getElementById("lastRefreshTime")
MDate1 = Match_Date.innerText
```

And I had tried the below and it gives me "Refreshed at:"

```
Set MDate= html.getElementsByClassName("wtext")(1)
MDate1 = Match_Date.innerText
```

i found some lines in the code about it. That seems is a javascript function. Is there anything still i can do for it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('lastRefreshTime').innerHTML = '26/05/2018 14:51';</script>
```

Comment: your `lastRefreshTime` span is being updated dynamically after the page loads. when you load your html into the `html` variable, it comes without text in the `lastRefreshTime` span and there is a javascript function somewhere on that page that updates this span. if you want to retrieve this date then you must do it with http request to where the javascript takes the data from.

Comment: @Banana Good point. I jumped the gun. I think an URL so we can inspect the page would really help.

Comment: is there an URL?

Comment: the `<script>` element is part of the document as well, you can retrieve it's content. but like @QHarr wrote above, it would be much easier to assist you if you can provide the URL or at least the full document html structure and the code where you load the document into your `html` object

Comment: Try using IE to fetch the content. Your approach seems to be accurate if the date you wanna parse are within second container of `wtext` class. It will be better if you put some delay before the line you mentioned above.